# php dom document remove some html tags but keep inner tags and text

Tags: php, html, tags, domdocument

I need to remove some tags (e.g. `<div></div>`) in HTML document and keep inner tags and text.
I managed to do that with Simple HTML Dom Parser. But it can't process big files due to huge memory requirements.
I would prefer to use native PHP tools like DOMDocument cause I read that it's more optimized and quicker in processing HTML documents.
But I struggle at the first stage - how to remove some tags while keeping inner text and tags.

Source HTML sample is:

```
<html><body><div>00000</div>aaaaa<div>bbbbbb<div>ccc<a>link</a>ccc</div>dddddd</div>eeeee<div>1111</div></body></html>
```

I try this code:

```
$htmltext='<html><body><div>00000</div>aaaaa<div>bbbbbb<div>ccc<a>link</a>ccc</div>dddddd</div>eeeee<div>1111</div></body></html>';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmltext);
$oldnodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($oldnodes as $node) {
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    while($node->childNodes->length > 0) {
        $fragment->appendChild($node->childNodes->item(0));
    }
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $node);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

It produces the output:

```
<html><body>00000aaaaa<div>bbbbbbccc<a>link</a>cccdddddd</div>eeeee<div>1111</div></body></html>
```

I need the following:

```
<html><body>00000aaaaabbbbbbccc<a>link</a>cccddddddeeeee1111</body></html>
```

Could someone please help me with proper code for the task?

Comment: If there are only a-Tags in your document body you could use strip_tags for that part using its second parameter for keeping a-tags in your string. Or you could use preg_replace to remove every div-tags in your HTML string.

Comment: There are lots of different tags, I want to remove only specific tags which are not only divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it work.
The reason code in question not working is the manipulation with nodes in nodelist ruin nodelist. So "foreach" function wents through only 2 out of 4 items in nodelist - the rest 2 become distorted.

So I had to deal with only the 1st element of the list and then rebuild list until there are some items in the list left.

The code is:

```
$htmltext='<html><body><div>00000</div>aaaaa<div>bbbbbb<div>ccc<a>link</a>ccc</div>dddddd</div>eeeee<div>1111</div></body></html>';
echo "<!-- 
".$htmltext."
-->
";
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmltext);
$oldnodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
while ($oldnodes->length>0){
    $node=$oldnodes->item(0);
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    while($node->childNodes->length > 0) {
        $fragment->appendChild($node->childNodes->item(0));
    }
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $node);
    $oldnodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

I hope that will be helpful for someone who finds same difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strip_tags function in PHP.

```
$thmltext = '<html><body><div>00000</div>aaaaa<div>bbbbbb<div>ccc<a>link</a>ccc</div>dddddd</div>eeeee<div>1111</div></body></html>';
strip_tags($htmltext, '<html>,<body>,<a>');
```

This remove all tags except *html,body,a*

And output is:

```
<html><body>00000aaaaabbbbbbccc<a>link</a>cccddddddeeeee1111</body></html>
```

**EDIT:**
If it is input from user, it's better for security reason to use whitelist tags and not blacklist.

Comment: Thanks,
It should work for this simple tags, but I need sometimes to choose which divs to delete based on their attributes. E.g. I may want do delete all divs except divs with id="mw-panel". That's why I try to get familiar with DOMdocument.

Answer (score 0):

If your code only contains simple HTML tags without any attributes you can keep it simple like:

```
$value = '<html><body><div>00000</div>aaaaa<div>bbbbbb<div>ccc<a>link</a>ccc</div>dddddd</div>eeeee<div>1111</div></body></html>';
$pattern = '/<[\/]*(div|h1)>/';

$removedTags = preg_replace($pattern, '', $value);
```

Since you wrote in your comment that there are more than just div tags you want to remove, I added a h1 tag to the pattern in case you also want to remove h1 tags.

This code snippet is only for simple code, but fits to your HTML input and output example.

Comment: Thank you for this option. Tags can contain attributes. I liked working with HTML as an DOM object with Simple HTML DOM. So it would be the best to understand how to apply standard tools like DOM Document to this task.

Comment: If this is just for obtaining knowledge than having a simple solution, then I don't need to post a pattern that also includes attributes. Removing multiple tags with DOMDocument can increase your amount of code. Let me see if I find some time to create a simple code snippet with DOMDocument.

Comment: I would say I need more universal solution cause I need to process ~300k pages in first batch. Of course I'm not able to post all of them here, but they can contain different attributes. I managed to create partly working solution with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. Partly - cause some pages are just too big for that parser to process (memory leaks).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
Just replace the for loop with the below code.

```
foreach ($oldnodes as $node) {
    $children = $node->childNodes;
    $string = "";
    foreach($children as $child) {
        $childString = $doc->saveXML($child);
        $string = $string."".$childString;
    }
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML($string);
    $node->parentNode->insertBefore($fragment,$node);
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Comment: I altered the code a bit cause there is no "appendHTML" but "appendXML"
And PHP doesn't allow to use $string."".$child - I have to use $string."".$node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child).

Altered code produces same result as in my question with my code - 

<html><body>00000aaaaa<div>bbbbbbccc<a>link</a>cccdddddd</div>eeeee<div>1111</div></body></html>

Comment: @user3240065  check the update code.sorry I forgot to add $childString = $doc->saveXML($child);

Comment: Thanks for your proposal of this option. I tried running the code - it still produces the same output as my code -

 <html><body>00000aaaaa<div>bbbbbbccc<a>link</a>cccdddddd</div>eeeee<div>1111</div></body></html>